# Demand aggregation with CES

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics

I am reading the [following paper](https://economics.mit.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/incomplete%20information%20in%20macro.pdf) by Angeletos and Lian and got stuck on equation (3). The problem is the standard optimal consumption bundle choice. Namely, aggregate consumption of "farmer" $i$ is

$$
c_i = \left(\int c_{ij}^{1-\eta} \mathrm{d}j\right)^{\frac{1}{1 - \eta}},
$$

and the budget constraint of the farmer is $\int p_j c_{ij}\mathrm{d}j = p_i q_i$, where $q_i$ is production of farmer $i$. Maximization of $c_i$ subject to a fixed aggregate expenditure yields the standard result

$$
\int p_j c_{ij}\mathrm{d}j = Pc_i 
$$
and

$$
\frac{c_{ij}}{c_i} = \left(\frac{p_j}{P}\right)^{-\frac{1}{\eta}}
$$
for all $j$, where $P = (\int p_j^{1 - 1/\eta}\mathrm{d}j)^{1/(1- 1/\eta)}$ is the ideal price index. Now the authors impose the market clearing condition $\int c_{ji} \mathrm{d}j = q_i$ for all $i$ and conclude from this that

$$
p_i = P\left(\frac{q_i}{Q}\right)^{-\eta}
$$
for all $i$, where $Q = (\int q_j^{1 - \eta} \mathrm{d}j)^{1/(1-\eta)}$ is supposed to be aggregate output. I cannot derive this result under the above assumptions.

What I tried was starting from

$$
c_{ji} = \left(\frac{p_i}{P}\right)^{-\frac{1}{\eta}}c_j
$$

(note this is just the optimal demand with switched indices). Integrating over $j$, and solving for $p_i$, I get

$$
p_i = P\left(\frac{q_i}{\int c_j \mathrm{d}j}\right)^{-\eta}.
$$
This is almost what I want, but I would need that $Q = \int c_j \mathrm{d}j$, which although maybe intuitive, does not seem to hold (compare by plugging in the definitions of $c_j$ and $q_j$). What am I missing? Thanks in advance!